# jQuery force redraw after inserting styles

Tags: jquery, css

I embed my stylesheet with jQuery through AJAX to replace the current font-family and do some testing with other font types.
That's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var page = $('#page').html();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/css/style.css',
        success: function(data){
            data = data.replace(/Arial/g, 'Verdana');

            $('#styles').html(data);

        },
        async: false
    })
});
</script>
<style type="text/css" id="styles"></style>
```

The problem is, the font-family isn't applied correctly. But once I open the dev tools the styles get applied. I guess a complete repaint of the page is needed. How can I achieve that without reloading the page?

Since this is only for testing I don't care about FOUC or perfomance issues here.

**EDIT**

I overlooked the typekit import in my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/****.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

It appears to be an issue with that. I think the font (I'm including "Europa" from typekit) is not ready yet when the AJAX request is made. Any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: sorry, try: `document.body.offsetHeight;` after adding new data

Comment: perhaps, try triggering the window resize after changing (`$(window).resize();`)

Comment: @skip405 i guess you mean resize right?!

Comment: Unfortunately both of these didn't work.. Is it possible to trigger a resize?

Comment: @enyce12 what about `$('body').hide().show(0);`

Comment: @A.Wolff That doesn't work neither...

Comment: @enyce12 any chance we can test it online?

Comment: @A.Wolff That's not possible, sorry. I've updated my question with further information.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to call ajax once script is loaded. The easier fix would be:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var page = $('#page').html();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/css/style.css',
        success: function(data){
            data = data.replace(/Arial/g, 'Verdana');

            $('#styles').html(data);

        },
        async: false
    })
});
```

BTW, i don't see any reason why you are setting request to async false, you should remove it.

Comment: I've found the problem. Thank you for your suggestions but this wasn't the solution. I had to remove all `@font-face` declarations in my CSS as they were causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a question on stackoverflow that is quite similar..
[CSS: Auto update font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715438/css-auto-update-font-size)

Maybe this works for you? It reflects what is written in comments about forcing resize event.

Here is fiddle from link:
http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rWYjk/

```
 causeRepaintsOn = $("h1, h2, h3, p");

 $(window).resize(function() {
    causeRepaintsOn.css("z-index", 1);
 });
```